# Paypal Express Checkout with ActiveMerchant as in Shopify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, e-commerce, paypal, activemerchant

I'm successfully using Paypal Express Checkout in a marketplace web app passing for every seller the three parameters to the PaypalExpressGateway (login, password and signature). 
So, I see that Shopify lets the seller set only the e-mail address of  the Paypal account requesting to grant scott_api1.jadedpixel.com as the API Partner Username. 
I could't find anything in the ActiveMerchant doc on how I can do it...Someone can help?

Thanks a lot,
zetarun

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use PayPals "Accelerated Boarding" method of setup for Express. They should send you an email after the first attempted sale with a link that automatically sets up the correct API settings.

To manually set them up, you can follow the instructions listed in our PayPal wiki, http://wiki.shopify.com/PayPal which are as follows:

Third-party authentication: Grant Shopify the appropriate API authentication permissions
  1. Log in to your PayPal account and click the Profile subtab.
  2. Click the API Access link in the Account Information column.
  3. Click the Grant API Permission link.
  4. In the Enter an API Partner Username field, enter scott_api1.jadedpixel.com.
  5. Check the following API permissions:
         * Express_Checkout
         * Direct_Payment
         * Admin_API
         * Auth_Settle
  6. Click the Save button.

Best regards,

Mike @ Shopify

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you very much for your answer.

Do you have an explained example on how to use your open source library (ActiveMerchant) to use Accelerated Boarding? Or it's an implementation that you have only for Shopify.com not developed in ActiveMerchant?

Thx,
Z.

Answer (score 1):

Ask the client to grant permissions on paypal and pass in the client's paypal email as :subject when creating an instance of the gateway:

```
ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalExpressGateway.new(
  :login => '...', :password => '...', :signature => '...',
  :subject => 'client@example.com')
```