# Paypal Activate 'Accelerated boarding'

Tags: paypal, payment

I have the same problem as in this question. [Paypal Express Checkout with ActiveMerchant as in Shopify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560690/paypal-express-checkout-with-activemerchant-as-in-shopify)

I want to implyment shopify like paypal payement. which consists on using third party account ( shopify paypal's account )  to do the checkout operations instead of merchants.

The merchant will give an email and the first time he gets a checkout from client, paypal will send him an email to set up an account. This method is good as it requires only an email account from the merchant.

The answer mention the world 'Accelerated boarding' which searching on google gives me nothing.

The question is outdated so I guess that paypal changed the name to another thing or it does not exist anymore.

Did any one now what was the destiny of 'Accelerated boarding' feature ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link to the integration approach for Express Checkout:
https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/limited-release/PP_AcceleratedBoarding_Guide.pdf

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.